# Changing the content of my index.php if user is logged in without creating another page?

Tags: php

See, I'm a newb to php. What I want is to make the user see some content if logged in and see the normal page if he is not logged in, without having to create another page. Because what I did before to accomplish that was create index.php and index2.php and the login.php redirecting to index2.php

Is it understandable without uploading the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    // ASSUMING YOU HAVE A CLASS THAT PRE-BUILDS HTML-MARKUP FOR EACH PAGE
    // THE CLASS MAY LOOK SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

    class MarkUpHelper{

        public static function getHomePage(){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Home-Page...
                    May require Database Access but here,
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }

        public static function getCustomizedUserPage($userID){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Customized User-Page...
                    May require Database Access using the $userID but here,
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }

        public static function getLoginPage(){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Login Page...
                    May require Database Access ...here...
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }

        public static function getRegistrationPage(){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Registration Page...
                    May require Database Access ...here...
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }

        public static function getSideBarLeft(){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Side-Bar Left Component(s)...
                    May require Database Access ...here...
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }

        public static function getSideBarRight(){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Side-Bar Right Component(s)...
                    May require Database Access ...here...
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }

        public static function getFooter(){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Footer Component(s)...
                    May require Database Access ...here...
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }

        public static function getHeader(){
            // YOU MAY EVEN LOAD/REQUIRE STATIC FILES: HTML, TXT, ETC
            // AND PARSE THE CONTENT TO A STRING (HTML-STRING)
            // AND THEN RETURN THE STRING VALUE
            return "HTML Markup for Header Component(s)...
                    May require Database Access ...here...
                    the HTML is generated & returned.";
        }
    }

?>
```

> Now inside `index.php` You may do something like:

```
<?php
    // AUTOLOAD OR MANUALLY INCLUDE THE MarkUpHelper CLASS
    // CHECK IF USER IS LOGGED IN, THEN BUILD THE CUSTOM USER-PAGE.
    // IF NOT,SIMPLY SHOW THE HOME-PAGE...
    // THE VARIABLE: $userIsLoggedIn ASSUMES THERE IS A WAY TO GET THIS.
    // THE VARIABLE: $userID ASSUMES THERE IS A WAY TO OBTAIN THIS VALUE: PERHAPS FROM $_SESSION
    if($userIsLoggedIn){
        $output = MarkUpHelper::getCustomizedUserPage($userID);
    }else{
        $output = MarkUpHelper::getHomePage();
    }

    echo $output;
```